# Remapping the values on a Razor form before posting to legacy application

Tags: forms, post, razor

I have a web form on a Razor cshtml page that needs to submit to a legacy application. The legacy application expects a `<select>` element with a hardcoded list of values.

That hardcoded list has changed. If I try to add a new option to this list, the legacy application will throw an error because it doesn't expect the new value.

I need to make the updated list available in the UI, and then remap the values before submitting them to the legacy application.

Her is a minimal example

```
<form action="/url/to/legacy.cfm method="POST">
    <select name="mylist" id="mylist_select">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <!-- the next option can't be here when the form is posted -->
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <input id="other" name="other_specify"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I added `option4`. The legacy application does not expect it, and throws an error as a result. So what I need to do is when the user clicks submit but before this form gets posted, `option4` needs to be removed, and the value of `other` needs to be set to "Option 4" as though the user just used the "Other" field on the page.

How can I do this with Razor?

EDIT: I know that this can be done fairly easy with JavaScript. I would prefer to do this with .NET instead though, so that the form can still be submitted without JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say if you must do this in the view on form submit, use JavaScript. Here is a simple example using jQuery (if you have it):

```
$("input:submit").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($("option:selected").val()=="option4")) {
        $("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#other").val("option4");

        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is definitely an acceptable answer, however, I would prefer to do this without JavaScript, so that the form can still be submitted without it being enabled.

Comment: @Scribblemacher I guess you could point the form to a `[HttpPost]` attributed `Action` in your MVC controller and make your alterations there then construct and post a HttpRequest to your legacy URL `/url/to/legacy.cfm` server-side